# My computer seems to randomly think I'm holding the Z key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Last week I spilled a Monster Energy drink on my laptop's keyboard and when I tried to clean it off it suddenly blue screened. After that it wouldn't boot any further than the BIOS. Now I tried booting it again today and to my surprise it worked but now every so often it acts like I'm holding down the Z key or sometimes the ` (grave accent) key. As far as I can tell those are the only two keys that are affected. It's really frustrating though as when I try to type (including this post) it randomly starts spamming the keys. It also does it even if I'm not touching the keyboard. As far as I can tell the only thing that seems to stop it for a moment is pressing the same key on both the built in keyboard (which is what the Monster spilled on) and my external keyboard. I took it to Best Buy when it wasn't getting past BIOS and they seemed to think it was a motherboard issue. Could that still be the case or if not what else could be causing this?

Comment: Apologies if this is formatted poorly or if I asked this on the wrong site but this seemed like the best place for it and I'm not sure how to better format it. Any further info needed I will be happy to provide.

Comment: Liquid over electronic components is bad. Did you try to clean? If it just dryed out there is still die let which may cause electric shortcuts. Find a way to clean it e.g. a computer shop or whatever

Comment: @papanito I dried it as best as I could with a bunch of paper towels. Later I also used 91% isopropyl alcohol to clean whatever it could and then thoroughly dried that with a hair dryer

Comment: The problem is you may need to open it to properly remove all dirt. Perhaps somebody has a better idea. Sorry I don't

Comment: @papanito hey I appreciate you even taking the time to respond. I don't have the tools or knowledge to safely get inside it myself though.

Comment: I always point people to this answer when they ask about liquid spills. The longer you leave it the worse it will get. Electronics do not heal themselves. Take it to a professional - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin then explain why, after leaving it for a while, it got better?

Comment: The original liquid dried out, reducing the electrical short… & now leaving the acidic residue to corrode the circuit board to its heart's content.

Comment: You need to remove the keyboard from the laptop. How this is done depends on the laptop brand and model. Then you can remove the keys and clean the area with alcohol.